# Prevent Nginx regex rule to override another rule

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have a Nginx server acting as a reverse proxy for a couple services, the config is similar to this one

```
location /backend/service1 {
        proxy_pass http://pathto/service1;
}

location / {
        root /a/folder
}

location ~* (\.js|\.css)$
        expires 8d;

        root /home/files/abc/bcd;
}
```

My problem here is that recently the service1 from backend has to serve a couple static files like `/backend/service1/something/file1.js` or `/backend/service1/something/style.css` and the second location, since it's a regex location rule, overrides the first one

All static files provided by backend/service1 have a certain prefix (`something`), so I tried to improve the regex from the second location to have negative lookahead/lookbehind, but it doesn't seem to work, probably because the main pattern has to have a fixed length (this is what i tried without luck)

```
location /backend/service1 {
        proxy_pass http://pathto/service1;
}

location / {
        root /a/folder
}

location ~* (?<!something)(.*)(\.js|\.css)$
        expires 8d;

        root /home/files/abc/bcd;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: I already checked the docs, but after checking it for the third time I came to a solution, see my answer below, so thanks I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "something" immediately follows `/backend/service1`, you can add another more specific `location` that takes precedence over regex locations:

```
location /backend/service1 {
    proxy_pass http://pathto/service1;
}  
location ^~ /backend/service1/something/ {
    proxy_pass http://pathto/service1/something/;
}  
location ~* \.(js|css)$ { ... }
```

If the "something" is embedded anywhere in the URL, you will need to use a regular expression, possibly with the *notorious* negative lookahead. By trial and error, I found a working expression:

```
location ~* ^(?!.*something).*\.(js|css)$ { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the other answer, but something that also worked for my case is nesting the location that had the regex. Something like this

```
location /backend/service1 {
        proxy_pass http://pathto/service1;
}

location / {
        location / {
            root /a/folder
        }

        location ~* (\.js|\.css)$
            expires 8d;

            root /home/files/abc/bcd;
        }
}
```

This way if the destination URI is prefixed by /backend/service1 the first location will trigger, for any other locations, the / location will trigger and then the regex can take effect

Comment: This solution does not answer your question. And is the same as using `location ^~ /backend/service1`

Comment: Why do you say that it does not answer my question? I fixed my issue doing this, is it wrong? Will give me issues in the future?

Comment: I will try later your solution because it is simpler, and if it works, I will accept your answer in favor of mine, but i actually did fix my issue with my approach, so I don't understand your comment

Comment: I am not saying that it does not solve your problem, and its good that you've found a solution that works for you. But the question you posted to SF specifically asked about a certain prefix "something", and this answer does not address that.

Comment: Your solution works and it's simpler so I accepted that and I edited this, thanks!